# Add re-using layout to scroll view

Tags: android, scrollview

I want to add to XML file (that includes one scroll view) re-using layout with this code:
`<include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>`
. But this error appears:

> Exception raised during rendering: ScrollView can host only one direct child

How should i add this tag to XML file?

Comment: Please post titlebar.xml and layout file that hosts the ScrollView.

Comment: titlebar.xml is about custom action bar and layout have one ScrollView and codes inside that (<ScrollView>some codes</ScrollView>). For example In ScrollView i use Linear and Relative layouts to add two TextView but in this case i don't know what can i do.

Comment: As the answer from Divers says, you can't have multiple children inside ScrollView, just one! From your reply, I guess you have more then one, but since you haven't posted the xml's I can't tell precisely what's wrong.

Comment: show me ur full code xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As exception text says, you can not have several children inside `ScrollView`. In order to fix it just wrap the content of `ScrollView`, including your `include`, into the layout (`LiniearLayout` for instance or what suite your needs).

Comment: That's right. It is best to put ScrollView always in to a Linear or Relative layout. Thank you!